# How does one age when travelling backwards in time?

Tags: tenet

In *Tenet*, the latest Christopher Nolan film, people can travel back in time. However, it's actually like the time passes in real time. So, how does one age when travelling back in time? Does one get older or younger?

Comment: From the traveler's perspective, they are still moving forwards, but everything around them is moving backwards. So I would think they are aging normally. But that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

When inverted, you personally experience time in the same way as if travelling forwards - you just see everything else travel in reverse.

So if you travel back a week after being inverted, you will still be a week older (and could possibly meet a version of yourself that is two weeks younger - because they have yet to travel the one week forward and second week inverted).

Comment: The book End of Eternity by Isaac Asimov that had a concept of physiotime, a person's normal aging outside of time.